# Terraform azure automation fails after the first deployment

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I have a silly question.
I am trying to deploy an azure web app using terraform. I have a task to build the code and drop it as a artefact, this works just fine. So I moved to the release process as follow

[image]

My code has a backend configuration in which I am saving my `terraform.tfstate` to be able to access this I create a `azure resource manager` service principle [image]

Now this works just perfectly for all my stages. I am able to create the resource group and the web app, and the `terraform.tfstate` get saved in the container which is under the `azure resource manager`

But here is my problem. If I update my code local and push it to GitHub the pipeline builds the artefact and the release triggers, but at the `plan` stage it fails with the following error.

```
reading resource group: resources.GroupsClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'XXXX' with object id 'XXX' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXX/resourcegroups/rg-hri-stg-eur-configurations' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."[0m
```

I do understand that once the resource group exists, I don't have permission to perform any action on it, such as `plan`, `apply` or `Destroy`.

I was wondering how can I set a azure resource manager for those pipeline to access this specific resource group once it has been created?

Thank you very much for any advice or help you can provide me with.

Comment: Hello @NaydenVan, What roles has been assigned to the client in the error ? I guess that client needs contributor access on the subscription scope , so that whenever a new resource group is created , the role will be automatically inherited for the newly created resource group as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. A silly one to be honest. My ARM resource was target a specific resource group(the one in which I keep my terraform states), so it was not working when trying to update a resource. I change the scope of the ARM resource to subscription level and everything works fine now. Thank you so much for your help guys